# Finding duplicate values in r

Tags: r

So, In a string containing multiple 1's,

Now, it is possible that, the number

```
'1'
```

appears at several positions, let's say, at multiple positions. What I want is

```
(3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how do you define which "1" is part of which group? Are you assuming fixed jumps?

Comment: As I said, if you take the first two `1` to be there, they dont satisfy the rule for minimum repetition to be for `1`.

Comment: I've edited. There is no 9 position actually

Comment: I don't have time for this right now, but you can identify significant seasonalities using `acf`. for example `acf(c(as.numeric(strsplit("1101101101", "")[[1]])))` will show you that yo have a significant seasonality of 3

Comment: Could do with some more examples. What do you want "101101001" to go to? How about "11110111111"?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I know you might be busy but it will be great if you can produce a reproducible code for the same. I tried with using your command but it just produces a bar graph. I want that specific output, please help me. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Spacedman, with `101101001`, the output will be, `(3,3,3) which means `1` appears at 3 and then 6 and then 9. :)

Comment: Would there also be more triplets for the 1s in position 1 and 4? I'm still not clear. Please add more complete examples to your question!

Comment: @Spacedman, there will be all the triplets that are actually possible for number `1` that satisfies the minimum repeating criteria. I can include more examples. If you take positions `4` and `1`, they dont form a triplet because there is no `1` at position `7`.

Comment: Have a look at `stringr::str_locate_all`

Comment: @Richard, I ran the command that you said, i.e. `s <- "1101101101"` and then `str_locate_all(s, "1")`, but what this does basically does is returns position of `1` in the entire string having the same value under the start and the end column. How can I actually combine them to form a triplet having fixed jumps ( period/difference ) that satisfy the threshold?

Comment: I find it really hard to believe that there is a unique set of results.  If some sequence yields `(1,3,10)` it'll also yield `(3,3,9)` and `(6,3,8)` and so on.

Comment: Although if I get `(1,3,10)` the sequences `(3,3,9)` will give me redundant information since their values have already been included in `(1,3,10)` , but even if I get both of them, I will be happy. :)

Comment: user3797829, please have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801741/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-single-string-of-characters-in-r/24945944#24945944). I worked hard on it and I believe it does everything you asked for, so I would be rather disappointed if you missed the bounty deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does exactly what you ask for. Try it with `str_groups('1101101101')`. It returns a list of 3-vectors. Note that the first triple is (1, 3, 4) because the character at the 10th position is also a 1.

### Final version, optimized and without errors

```
str_groups <- function (s) {
    digits <- as.numeric(strsplit(s, '')[[1]])
    index1 <- which(digits == 1)
    len <- length(digits)
    back <- length(index1)
    if (back == 0) return(list())
    maxpitch <- (len - 1) %/% 2
    patterns <- matrix(0, len, maxpitch)
    result <- list()

    for (pitch in 1:maxpitch) {
        divisors <- which(pitch %% 1:(pitch %/% 2) == 0)
        while (index1[back] > len - 2 * pitch) {
            back <- back - 1
            if (back == 0) return(result)
        }
        for (startpos in index1[1:back]) {
            if (patterns[startpos, pitch] != 0) next
            pos <- seq(startpos, len, pitch)
            if (digits[pos[2]] != 1 || digits[pos[3]] != 1) next
            repeats <- length(pos)
            if (repeats > 3) for (i in 4:repeats) {
                if (digits[pos[i]] != 1) {
                    repeats <- i - 1
                    break
                }
            }
            continue <- F
            for (subpitch in divisors) {
                sublen <- patterns[startpos, subpitch]
                if (sublen > pitch / subpitch * (repeats - 1)) {
                    continue <- T
                    break
                }
            }
            if (continue) next
            for (i in 1:repeats) patterns[pos[i], pitch] <- repeats - i + 1
            result <- append(result, list(c(startpos, pitch, repeats)))
        }
    }

    return(result)
}
```

Note: this algorithm has roughly quadratic runtime complexity, so if you make your strings twice as long, it will take four times as much time to find all patterns on average.

### Pseudocode version

To aid understanding of the code. For particulars of R functions such as `which`, consult the R online documentation, for example by running `?which` on the R command line.

```
PROCEDURE str_groups WITH INPUT $s (a string of the form /(0|1)*/):
    digits := array containing the digits in $s
    index1 := positions of the digits in $s that are equal to 1
    len := pointer to last item in $digits
    back := pointer to last item in $index1
    IF there are no items in $index1, EXIT WITH empty list
    maxpitch := the greatest possible interval between 1-digits, given $len
    patterns := array with $len rows and $maxpitch columns, initially all zero
    result := array of triplets, initially empty

    FOR EACH possible $pitch FROM 1 TO $maxpitch:
        divisors := array of divisors of $pitch (including 1, excluding $pitch)
        UPDATE $back TO the last position at which a pattern could start;
            IF no such position remains, EXIT WITH result
        FOR EACH possible $startpos IN $index1 up to $back:
            IF $startpos is marked as part of a pattern, SKIP TO NEXT $startpos
            pos := possible positions of pattern members given $startpos, $pitch
            IF either the 2nd or 3rd $pos is not 1, SKIP TO NEXT $startpos
            repeats := the number of positions in $pos
            IF there are more than 3 positions in $pos THEN
                count how long the pattern continues
                UPDATE $repeats TO the length of the pattern
            END IF (more than 3 positions)
            FOR EACH possible $subpitch IN $divisors:
                check $patterns for pattern with interval $subpitch at $startpos
                IF such a pattern is found AND it envelopes the current pattern,
                    SKIP TO NEXT $startpos
                    (using helper variable $continue to cross two loop levels)
                END IF (pattern found)
            END FOR (subpitch)
            FOR EACH consecutive position IN the pattern:
                UPDATE $patterns at row of position and column of $pitch TO ...
                    ... the remaining length of the pattern at that position
            END FOR (position)
            APPEND the triplet ($startpos, $pitch, $repeats) TO $result
        END FOR (startpos)
    END FOR (pitch)

    EXIT WITH $result
END PROCEDURE (str_groups)
```

Comment: This is really great. Thanks a lot Julian. This is amazing. You deserve much more than this bounty.

Comment: Also Julian, it will be great if you can give me some insights on reducing the complexity for the code? Thanks. :)

Comment: You're welcome. To be honest, I don't think the runtime complexity can be reduced, because the task inherently requires looking at the remainder of the list for every element in the list. The lines marked with `###` already serve to avoid duplicate work, but the order of complexity remains quadratic. (**Edit**) You might be able to optimize this by first generating a list with the positions of all 1 digits. However, the code would become more complicated.

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines, like generate a list of all 1's and find all possible Arithmetic Progressions.

Comment: I tried doing this. `str_groups('110110110110110')`. I got 4 triplets. Now, I have a doubt. Two of the triplets that I got were, `1 3 5` and `1 6 3`. Now, ` 1 3 5 ` corresponds to the position of `1` at `1 4 7 10 13` and ` 1 6 3 ` corresponds to the position of `1` at `1 7 13`. So, they give the same information which appears to be redundant. Anyway we can remove this?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer to rule out such sub-patterns with larger intervals. The newly inserted code is marked with `##<`.

Comment: I don't think it still works. Try running it `str_groups('1101101101101101')`. Two of the output comes out to be `1 3 6` and `4 6 3`. By the first pattern, it is, `1 4 7 10 13 16` and by the second it is, `4 10 16` which again appears to be redundant.

Comment: Good call. I have now edited the post again to cover those cases as well.

Comment: it is also missing out some of the patterns. See for yourself.  `str_groups('1111101010111111')` . Gives only two triplets, `1 1 5` and `11  1  6`. As you can see, the `1` is appearing at `5 7 9 11` as well. Therefore, there should be an additional triplet `5 2 4`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58062/discussion-between-user3797829-and-julian).

Comment: It is happening because of the new code that prevents sub-patterns with larger pitch. You'll see that the triplet (5, 2, 4) (which by the way should be (1, 2, 8)) is not omitted if you remove the lines marked with `##<`. I'm currently working on a new fix... :P

Comment: I have updated the program again, please [re-visit the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58062/discussion-between-user3797829-and-julian).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but some ideas (partly based on comments):

```
z <- "1101101101"
zz <- as.numeric(strsplit(z,"")[[1]])
```

Compute autocorrelation function and draw plot: in this case I'm getting the periodicity=3 pretty crudely as the first point at which there is an increase followed by a decrease ...

```
a1 <- acf(zz)
first.peak <- which(diff(sign(diff(a1$acf[,,1])))==-2)[1]
```

Now we know the periodicity is 3; create runs of 3 with `embed()` and analyze their similarities:

```
ee <- embed(zz,first.peak)
pp <- apply(ee,1,paste,collapse="")
mm <- outer(pp,pp,"==")
aa <- apply(mm[!duplicated(mm),],1,which)
sapply(aa,length)  ## 3 3 2   ## number of repeats
sapply(aa,function(x) unique(diff(x)))  ## 3 3 3
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but it helped. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following route will help:

1. Convert string to a vector of integers characters

   ```
   v <- as.integer(strsplit(s, "")[[1]])
   ```
2. Repeatedly convert this vector to matrices of varying number of rows...

   ```
   m <- matrix(v, nrow=...)
   ```
3. ...and use `rle` to find relevant patterns in the **rows** of the matrix `m`:

   ```
   rle(m[1, ]); rle(m[2, ]); ...
   ```

Comment: How will `rle` help me? `rle` basically finds the longest length encoding. I dont want that. I have gaps in between as well for two consecutive `1`.

Comment: Well, I did this. `m <- matrix(s, nrow=5)`. (For all value upto 5). Then ran these commands, `rle(m[1, ])` , `rle(m[2, ])` , `rle(m[3, ])` . And I got the same result back. Which was, `Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int 1
  values : chr "110110110" `
I cannot see any repetition rule here. ` :)

Comment: @user3797829: Have you tried `matrix(v, ...)`, with `v` prepared as in step 1 (it's a sequence, not a list of alternatives...).

Comment: I got what you were trying to do. For example, I got the output as, `Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:6] 2 1 2 1 2 1
  values : int [1:6] 1 0 1 0 1 0` on having no. of rows as 1 in the matrix, and I can see the output as well, but but, I will be doing it for many rows. I want some logic by which R can automatically analyse the triplets and give me them ( not necessarily in that form, other form will do ). This is for continuous length encoding. That is, the value `1` appears `2` times, then the value `0` appears 1 times. I want something that will give me the output as above. :)