# Parsing through a string counting and removing infrequent characters in r

Tags: r

So, I have a file like this.

```
"1" "4" "10"     "11111111111111"
"2" "10" "22"    "11111111110111"
"3" "10" "295"   "11111111111100"
"4" "10" "584"   "11010000000000"
"5" "10" "403"   "11111111110111"
"6" "10" "281"   "11110101011110"
"7" "10" "123"   "11100000100100"
"8" "10" "127"   "11111111111111"
"9" "10"  "79"   "11110111111111"
"10" "10" "1030" "11110000000100"
................................
```

I want to remove those rows from this file, which have less than 4 '1' in the string in the column 4 for a particular row.
For example, the row 4 contains the string "11010000000000". The string has only 3 '1', so I want to remove this row from the file.

PS: One way I thought of was to convert the string into individual characters and paste them in different columns for a particular row and then remove those rows having less than 4 '1'. Is there any other direct way I can do it?

Answer (score 5):

The better string processing packages (like "stringi") will often have a feature to count the occurrences of certain patterns:

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_fixed(str=mydf$V4, pattern="1")
#  [1] 14 13 12  3 13 10  5 14 13  5
```

But you can also do this in base R.

```
vapply(regmatches(mydf$V4, gregexpr("1", mydf$V4)), length, 1L)
#  [1] 14 13 12  3 13 10  5 14 13  5
```

---

You can then use that vector of results to subset using basic comparison operators.

Comment: Great answer. I am interested in this question, but as you can see there is no answer to it, can you have a look on it?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801741/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-single-string-of-characters-in-r?noredirect=1#comment38497819_24801741

Comment: can you have a look at it?

Comment: @user3845968, I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do in the other question.

Comment: Well as an R enthusiast like you, I was going through the question. Well, I found that it hasnt been answered yet. I started solving it. But I wasnt able to. I am not able to guess how should I actually proceed. The question as it states, basically needs as output the value of `1` which is getting repeated ( minimum number of times 3 ). Now, that `1` can start from anywhere. I guess the example is self explanatory. How can it be done? Thanks for looking. :)

Comment: I wish to know if such a thing can be done in R? I mean, whatever the other user has posted in that question, can something in R actually achieve it? I have no doubt over the great power of R, but questions like these make me curious.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the zeros and keep those rows for which what is left has at least 4 characters.  Here we assume that the data is in a data frame named `DF` and its fourth column has name `V4`:

```
subset(DF, nchar(gsub("0", "", V4)) >= 4)
```

or a bit faster but perhaps slightly less readable:

```
DF[nchar(gsub("0", "", DF$V4)) >= 4, ]
```

**Added** Second variation.

Answer (score 1):

This is another option in base R using regular expressions:

```
min.num <- 4
d[grepl(paste(rep(1, min.num), collapse='.*'), d[[4]]), ]

#    V1 V2   V3             V4
# 1   1  4   10 11111111111111
# 2   2 10   22 11111111110111
# 3   3 10  295 11111111111100
# 5   5 10  403 11111111110111
# 6   6 10  281 11110101011110
# 7   7 10  123 11100000100100
# 8   8 10  127 11111111111111
# 9   9 10   79 11110111111111
# 10 10 10 1030 11110000000100
```

Benchmarking results:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(stringi)

grothendieck <- function(DF) subset(DF, nchar(gsub("0", "", V4)) >= 4)
plourde <- function(d) d[grepl(paste(rep(1, 4), collapse='.*'), d[[4]]), ]
mahto1 <- function(mydf) mydf[stri_count_fixed(str=mydf$V4, pattern="1") > 3, ]
mahto2 <- function(mydf) mydf[vapply(regmatches(mydf$V4, gregexpr("1", mydf$V4)), length, 1L) > 3, ]

microbenchmark(grothendieck(d), plourde(d), mahto1(d), mahto2(d))

# Unit: microseconds
#             expr     min      lq  median      uq   max neval
#  grothendieck(d)  2895.7  2979.9  3003.8  3043.3  3444   100
#       plourde(d)  1280.2  1299.5  1317.6  1341.1  1542   100
#        mahto1(d)   518.2   532.3   545.8   554.5  1269   100
#        mahto2(d) 25465.3 27409.6 28447.0 29858.6 45734   100
```

Comment: That works . Thanks. :)
Also, can you look at this question as well? I am having difficulties solving it. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801741/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-single-string-of-characters-in-r?noredirect=1#comment38497819_24801741

Comment: I tried `groth2 <- function(DF) DF[nchar(gsub('0','',DF[,4])) >=4,]
` and `microbenchmark` showed it to be faster than `grothendieck` but not  as fast as `plourde`