# Removing rows which contain all 0's in r

Tags: r

I have a file like this.

```
"1" "4" "10" "ttts" 3
"2" "10" "22" "ttt" 2
"3" "10" "295" "00000" 13
"4" "10" "584" "0t000000" 5
"5" "10" "403" "000s" 15
"6" "10" "281" "000" 19
"7" "10" "123" "000q" 16
"8" "10" "127" "000" 20
........................
```

What I want is that all the rows which contains all `0` in the fourth column, such as the rows `3` and the rows `6` along with row `8` are eliminated. How can I do this in R?
Thanks!

Comment: You mean to say you really couldn't extend [one of the options summarized in Matthew's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24805476/1270695) to answer this question?

Comment: How are you reading this data into R?  Let's start there.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` is probably the most efficient way of doing this:

```
data = read.table(header = TRUE, text = "  X2  X3       X4 X5
1  4  10     ttts  3
2 10  22      ttt  2
3 10 295    00000 13
4 10 584 0t000000  5
5 10 403     000s 15
6 10 281      000 19
7 10 123     000q 16
8 10 127      000 20")

data[!grepl("^0+$", data[,3]),]
#  X2  X3       X4 X5
#1  4  10     ttts  3
#2 10  22      ttt  2
#4 10 584 0t000000  5
#5 10 403     000s 15
#7 10 123     000q 16
```

Edit: Changed `grep` to `grepl` as per commenter's suggestions.

Comment: You may want `invert = TRUE`.  I think OP wants to remove these lines.

Comment: Well, if you're gonna go that route, `!grepl(...)` might be safer.

Comment: @RichardScriven If you don't mind me asking, why go with `!grepl(…)` rather than `-grep(…)`?

Comment: Compare `data[-grep("x", data[,3]),]` and `data[!grepl("x", data[,3]),]` to see what @RichardScriven might be referring to. My guess is that the `grep` result would be unexpected by many unless it has bitten them in the past.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks, I hadn't considered that case, changed the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that row 8 should also be dropped.

I would suggest trying the "stringi" package and doing something like this:

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_fixed(mydf[, 4], "0") == nchar(mydf[, 4])
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can use this logical vector to subset from your original dataset.

---

In base R, you can also try:

```
vapply(strsplit(mydf[, 4], ""), function(x) all(x == "0"), logical(1L))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: how do I get the final file? Don't just want a logical index which says if it is true or not? Thanks. :)

Comment: @user3845968, subsetting based on a logical index is very basic R and is covered in all introductory manuals. This would be your row index in your `[row, col]` type of extraction command.

Comment: Note that this also assumes `mydf[,4]` is a character vector, for `nchar()` @user3845968, how are you reading this file into R?

Comment: @RichardScriven, I did it by setting `colClasses = 'character'`.

Comment: @user3845968, first of all, you should note that I had mentioned `[row, col]` specification. Second, you will need to negate these results. I give in: `mydf[!logic, ]`. Yes. The "col" specification is blank--that means to return all columns.

Comment: @user3845968, I suggest re-reading using `read.table("yourFile.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` instead of `colClasses` since it seems you have some numeric columns.  That's it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

```
indx <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,4])) #all the non-numeric elements coerced to NA

 data[!(!is.na(indx) & !indx),]
#   V1 V2  V3       V4 V5
# 1  1  4  10     ttts  3
# 2  2 10  22      ttt  2
# 4  4 10 584 0t000000  5
# 5  5 10 403     000s 15
# 7  7 10 123     000q 16
```

#### Explanation

Using a more general example that includes numbers other 0

```
v1 <- c("ttts", "ttt", "00000", "0t000000", "000s", "000", "000q", 
"000", "001")
indx <-suppressWarnings(as.numeric(v1)) #coerce non-numeric elements to NA
indx
#[1] NA NA  0 NA NA  0 NA  0  1
```

To exclude all `0` elements from the rest

```
indx1 <- !is.na(indx) & !indx #elements that are all 0's are TRUE
indx1
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Negate that

```
!(indx1)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

v1[!(indx1)]
#[1] "ttts"     "ttt"      "0t000000" "000s"     "000q"     "001"
```

Comment: Could use some explanation, but +1.